# My text isn't appearing and disappearing when I click on this picture using toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm practicing my javascript with others trying to basically make my text underneath my picture appear and disappear when I click on the picture. I've been using toggle from JQuery but am not having any luck in getting my text to disappear or appear. What am I missing? Or what should I add! Thanks lots...and here comes the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="something_style.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">

</head>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#col1").click(function(){
        $('p').toggle();
   });
 });
 </script>

<body> 
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="outerWrapper">
 <div id="header"><a href="https:www.medium.com"><img src="http://ncadpostgraduate.com/images/site/header.gif" alt="NCAD Postgraduate Study" width="366" height="66" /></a></div> 
  <div id="topNavigation">

  </div></div>
  </div><div id="wrapper-3">
  <div id="outerWrapper">
  <div id="contentWrapperhome">
    <div id="col1"><a><img src="image/DSC04580.JPG" alt="NCAD Entrance" width="251" height="251" /></a>
<div id="text">
        <h1><a href="http://ncadpostgraduate.com/index.php/postgraduate">Postgraduate Study</a></h1>
        <p><a href="http://ncadpostgraduate.com/index.php/postgraduate">This is me isn't it?</a></p>
</div>
    </div>    
    <div id="col1"><a><img src="image/DSC04580.JPG" alt="Prospectus Image" width="251" height="251" />
     </a><div id="text">
      <h1><a>Prospectus</a></h1>
      <p><a>Read the full Postgraduate prospectus for 2009/2010 online, including details regarding Application deadlines and procedures. The Prospectus is also available as a PDF download.</a></p>
    </div></div>

    <div id="col1"><a><img src="image/DSC04580.JPG" alt="Graduate Work Image" width="251" height="251">
      </a><div id="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have more than one element per ID, you have several with `id=col1` change that to classes or make them individual for starters.  Good thing about using classes is that you can attach one listener to many elements.  Then toggle the `p` under that or `this` by limiting your selector.

HTML:

```
<div id="header"><a href="https:www.medium.com"><img src="http://ncadpostgraduate.com/images/site/header.gif" alt="NCAD Postgraduate Study" width="366" height="66" /></a>

</div>
<div id="topNavigation"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper-3">
    <div id="outerWrapper">
        <div id="contentWrapperhome">
            <div class="clickToHideClass"><a><img src="image/DSC04580.JPG" alt="NCAD Entrance" width="251" height="251" /></a>

                <div id="text">
                     <h1><a href="http://ncadpostgraduate.com/index.php/postgraduate">Postgraduate Study</a></h1>

                    <p><a href="http://ncadpostgraduate.com/index.php/postgraduate">This is me isn't it?</a>

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clickToHideClass"><a><img src="image/DSC04580.JPG" alt="Prospectus Image" width="251" height="251" />
     </a>

                <div id="text">
                     <h1><a>Prospectus</a></h1>

                    <p><a>Read the full Postgraduate prospectus for 2009/2010 online, including details regarding Application deadlines and procedures. The Prospectus is also available as a PDF download.</a>

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clickToHideClass"><a><img src="image/DSC04580.JPG" alt="Graduate Work Image" width="251" height="251">
      </a>

                <div id="text">
                     <h1><a>Prospectus</a></h1>

                    <p><a>Read the full Postgraduate prospectus for 2009/2010 online, including details regarding Application deadlines and procedures. The Prospectus is also available as a PDF download.</a>

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".clickToHideClass").click(function () {
         // now toggle only the 'p' under 'this'
         $('p', $(this)).toggle();
     });
 });
```

and working Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/EuJB6/

Comment: Thanks! This actually worked for me. 

But there's one thing Im wondering about as far as the CSS goes. I want the text originally hidden from the start so I set it as 

display:none;

However, after I do that, I notice the toggle function not working anymore. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, have a look at the updated demo here http://jsfiddle.net/EuJB6/2/
Look at the CSS and what it applies to.

Answer (score 0):

Close script tag so it must working

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#col1").click(function () {
                    $('p').toggle();
                });
            });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="outerWrapper">
            <div id="header"><a href="https:www.medium.com"><img src="http://ncadpostgraduate.com/images/site/header.gif" alt="NCAD Postgraduate Study" width="366" height="66" /></a></div>
            <div id="topNavigation">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div><div id="wrapper-3">
    <div id="outerWrapper">
        <div id="contentWrapperhome">
            <div id="col1">
                <a><img src="image/DSC04580.JPG" alt="NCAD Entrance" width="251" height="251" /></a>
                <div id="text">
                    <h1><a href="http://ncadpostgraduate.com/index.php/postgraduate">Postgraduate Study</a></h1>
                    <p><a href="http://ncadpostgraduate.com/index.php/postgraduate">This is me isn't it?</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="col1">
                <a>
                    <img src="image/DSC04580.JPG" alt="Prospectus Image" width="251" height="251" />
                </a><div id="text">
                    <h1><a>Prospectus</a></h1>
                    <p><a>Read the full Postgraduate prospectus for 2009/2010 online, including details regarding Application deadlines and procedures. The Prospectus is also available as a PDF download.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="col1">
                <a>
                    <img src="image/DSC04580.JPG" alt="Graduate Work Image" width="251" height="251">
                </a><div id="text">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your HTML needed tidying up.  Ensure you close the `</head>` and place your Javascript in the `<head>`.  ie

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="something_style.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  // do summit
 });
</script>
```

Also the `<body>` html needed tidying up ie:

```
<div class="col"><img src="image/DSC04580.JPG" alt="Prospectus Image" width="251" height="251" /></div>
     <div class="text">
      <h1>Prospectus</h1>
      <p>Read the full Postgraduate prospectus for 2009/2010 online, including details regarding Application deadlines and procedures. The Prospectus is also available as a PDF download.</p>
    </div>

<div class="col"><img src="image/DSC04580.JPG" alt="Graduate Work Image" width="251" height="251"></div>
  <div class="text">
  <h1>Other text</h1>
  <p>Read the full Postgraduate prospectus for 2009/2010 online, including details regarding Application deadlines and procedures. The Prospectus is also available as a PDF download.</p>
    </div>
```

Note how the ID are replaced with class.  IDs should be unique.  Finally the Javascript needed amending as follows:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.col').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.text').toggle();
   });
 });
</script>
```

This now uses the classes `col` and `text` and makes use of `$(this).next()` to only toggle the next occurrence of a element of class `text`.